# Single-node validator stuck on "Haven't landed a vote, so skipping my leader slot"

Tags: validator, local-cluster, vote-account

What are the steps to getting a single-node validator in a private network (using the `solana-validator` binary) running? The current setup I'm doing is

```
solana-genesis \
  --enable-warmup-epochs \
  --cluster-type development \
  --bootstrap-validator "$HOME/validator-keypair.json" "$HOME/vote-account-keypair.json" "$HOME/validator-stake-keypair.json" \
  --ledger "$LEDGER_DIR"

solana-validator \
  --allow-private-addr \
  --enable-rpc-transaction-history \
  --full-rpc-api \
  --no-poh-speed-test \
  --dynamic-port-range 8200-8300 \
  --identity "$HOME/validator-keypair.json" \
  --incremental-snapshot-interval-slots 200 \
  --log "$LEDGER_DIR/validator.log" \
  --public-rpc-address "$GOSSIP_HOST:8111" \
  --vote-account "$HOME/vote-account-keypair.json" \
  --ledger "$LEDGER_DIR"
```

but my validator is stuck with messages saying `Haven't landed a vote, so skipping my leader slot` after the initial `____ reset PoH to tick 64 (within slot 0). My next leader slot is 1`.

If I pass the `--no-wait-for-vote-to-start-leader` flag to the validator, I instead get messages saying `slot_state_update: DuplicateConfirmed(DuplicateConfirmedState { duplicate_confirmed_hash: ___, bank_status: Frozen(___) })`.

Are there any flags I need to pass during genesis or to the validator to allow it to run and permanently stay as the single-node leader?

Comment: This doesn't address your exact question, since you're asking about how to run a single `solana-validator` instance, but how about just using `solana-test-validator`? That gives all of the functionality that you need without the gossip and voting, which are unnecessary for a single-validator cluster.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this? I am seeing the same results trying to start my own cluster...